# ListView inside a Fragment in a VerticalViewPager in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using Jack Wharton's Android DirectionalViewPager (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-DirectionalViewPager) to scroll fragments vertically. I have two fragments, one of these have a 47deg's SwipeListView (https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview). The problem is that when user is on the fragment with the SwipeListView he can't scroll the list because inmediately change to the other fragment because the DirectionalViewPager.

Questions

1. ¿Can I capture the scroll events of the SwipeListView in a different way to work together with the scroll of the DirectionalViewPager?
2. ¿It's posible to scroll with one finger to change inside the listview and with two fingers to scroll inside the DirectionalViewPager? If that's possible, ¿How can I do that?
3. ¿Do you have any other suggestion to solve this problem?

I'd really appreciate your help.

Thank you

ComprasActivity.java

```
package com.easyshopping.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import com.directionalviewpager.DirectionalViewPager;
import com.easyshopping.easyshopping.R;


public class ComprasActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Fragments
    public static Fragment[] fragmentos = new Fragment[2];

    /**
     * The number of pages (wizard steps) to show in this demo.
     */
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_compras);

        // Set up the pager
        final DirectionalViewPager pager = (DirectionalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        pager.setOrientation(DirectionalViewPager.VERTICAL);

    }

    /**
     * A simple pager adapter that represents 5 ScreenSlidePageFragment objects,
     * in sequence.
     */
    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentos[1] = new ShoppingListFragment();
            fragmentos[0] = new CameraTestFragment();

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragmentos[position];

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

ShoppingListFragment.java

```
package com.easyshopping.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.easyshopping.easyshopping.R;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.BaseSwipeListViewListener;
import com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ShoppingListFragment extends Fragment {

    SwipeListView myListView;
    ArrayList<String> myStringArray1;
    ShoppingListAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shoppinglist, container, false);

        myListView = (SwipeListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingList);

        myStringArray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");
        myStringArray1.add("something");

        adapter = new ShoppingListAdapter(getActivity(), myStringArray1);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        myListView.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(int position, boolean toRight) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onClosed(int position, boolean fromRight) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onListChanged() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMove(int position, float x) {
                Log.d("MOVE_LIST", "pos: " + position + "; float: " + x);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartOpen %d - action %d", position, action));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartClose(int position, boolean right) {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onStartClose %d", position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickFrontView %d", position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onClickBackView(int position) {
                Log.d("swipe", String.format("onClickBackView %d", position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onDismiss(int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                    myStringArray1.remove(position);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });

        return rootView;

    }

}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I suggest you avoid using DirectionalViewPager, as it's no longer supported, unless you want to handle any issues with it yourself.

A Google search shows me these more recent implementations of a vertical ViewPager:

https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager
https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my comment to your question, I investigated one of the libraries I linked to. It turns out that [this one](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/)* supports vertical scrolling content inside the vertical ViewPager. For your questions:

> Can I capture the scroll events of the SwipeListView in a different
>   way to work together with the scroll of the DirectionalViewPager?

You can subclass the ViewPager and override `onInterceptTouchEvent()`, stopping the ViewPager from moving to the next page until the ListView reaches scrolls to its last child.

> It's posible to scroll with one finger to change inside the listview
>   and with two fingers to scroll inside the DirectionalViewPager? If
>   that's possible, ¿How can I do that?

It is possible, but I strongly suggest you don't do that. Think about your users and usability. Again, the key to this would be using `onInterceptTouchEvent()`.

> Do you have any other suggestion to solve this problem?

Yes. Use a different library, like I suggested earlier. [This VerticalViewPager](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager) already handles it for you. See [this line](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/blob/master/src/VerticalViewPager.java#L1754) of the source code to see how it does. The DirectionalViewPager you're using is deprecated.

**This does not mean that the other library does not also support vertical scrolling, it means I only checked one of the two.*

Comment: Thank you so much. LambergaR's Vertical ViewPager works for me. I just create a different adapter (FragmentPagerAdapter) and that solved my problem. I didn't have to use onInterceptTouchEvent().